# Sorting array of object with multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this array:

```json
var array = [{
   "datecrea":"2020-01-31T16:14:46+01:00",
   "datas":{
      "badge":"new",
      "downloads":1,
   },
},
{
   "datecrea":"2020-01-31T17:14:46+01:00",
   "datas":{
      "badge":"soon",
      "downloads":0,
   },
},
{
   "datecrea":"2020-01-31T18:14:46+01:00",
   "datas":{
      "badge":"",
      "downloads":3,
   },
},
{
   "datecrea":"2020-01-31T19:14:46+01:00",
   "datas":{
      "badge":"topten",
      "downloads":5,
   },
},
{
   "datecrea":"2020-01-31T20:14:46+01:00",
   "datas":{
      "badge":"new",
      "downloads":1,
   },
}]
```

I want to sort this array but using multiple values and here's the sorting steps:

1. badge
2. "soon" is the most important
3. "new"
4. "topten" is the least important one
5. downloads
6. datecrea

I already have this code which sorts by date and then by downloads:

```js
array.sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date(b.datecrea) - new Date(a.datecrea);
})
.sort(function(a,b){
    return b.datas.downloads - a.datas.downloads;
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write three `sort()` methods. You can do it in one `sort()`.

Something like this:

```js
var array = [{
    "datecrea": "2020-01-31T16:14:46+01:00",
    "datas": {
      "badge": "new",
      "downloads": 1,
    },
  },
  {
    "datecrea": "2020-01-31T17:14:46+01:00",
    "datas": {
      "badge": "soon",
      "downloads": 0,
    },
  },
  {
    "datecrea": "2020-01-31T18:14:46+01:00",
    "datas": {
      "badge": "",
      "downloads": 3,
    },
  },
  {
    "datecrea": "2020-01-31T19:14:46+01:00",
    "datas": {
      "badge": "topten",
      "downloads": 5,
    },
  },
  {
    "datecrea": "2020-01-31T20:14:46+01:00",
    "datas": {
      "badge": "new",
      "downloads": 1,
    },
  }
]

const badgeWeights = {
  soon: 3,
  new: 2,
  topten: 1,
};

const result = array.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.datecrea !== b.datecrea) {
    return new Date(b.datecrea) - new Date(a.datecrea);
  }
  
  if (a.datas.downloads !== b.datas.downloads) {
    return b.datas.downloads - a.datas.downloads;
  }
  
  const aWeight = a.datas.badge ? badgeWeights[a.datas.badge] : 0;
  const bWeight = b.datas.badge ? badgeWeights[b.datas.badge] : 0;
  
  return bWeight - aWeight;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make an array of the badge strings, based on their "importance", then have a `.sort` function which sorts by:

- the difference in the `datecrea`s. If zero, then by
- the difference in the `downloads`. If zero, then by
- The difference in the index of the badge in the badge string array

```
const badges = ['soon', 'new', 'topten', ''];
array.sort((a, b) => (
  (badges.indexOf(a.datas.badge) - badges.indexOf(b.datas.badge)) ||
  (new Date(b.datecrea) - new Date(a.datecrea)) ||
  (b.datas.downloads - a.datas.downloads)
));
```

```js
const badges = ['soon', 'new', 'topten', ''];
var array = [{
   "datecrea":"2020-01-31T16:14:46+01:00",
   "datas":{
      "badge":"new",
      "downloads":1,
   },
},
{
   "datecrea":"2020-01-31T17:14:46+01:00",
   "datas":{
      "badge":"soon",
      "downloads":0,
   },
},
{
   "datecrea":"2020-01-31T18:14:46+01:00",
   "datas":{
      "badge":"",
      "downloads":3,
   },
},
{
   "datecrea":"2020-01-31T19:14:46+01:00",
   "datas":{
      "badge":"topten",
      "downloads":5,
   },
},
{
   "datecrea":"2020-01-31T20:14:46+01:00",
   "datas":{
      "badge":"new",
      "downloads":1,
   },
},
{
   "datecrea":"2020-01-31T20:14:46+01:00",
   "datas":{
      "badge":"",
      "downloads":1,
   },
}]

array.sort((a, b) => (
  (badges.indexOf(a.datas.badge) - badges.indexOf(b.datas.badge)) ||
  (b.datas.downloads - a.datas.downloads) ||
  (new Date(b.datecrea) - new Date(a.datecrea))
));
console.log(array);
```

Don't call `.sort` twice - only call it once, and put all the logic in that one callback. If you `.sort` twice, the sorted results from the first `.sort` will be lost, because the array will get completely re-sorted by the second `.sort`.

Comment: Thank you so mush @CertainPerformance for you answer, but I'have changed my question, I gave the wong steps, in fact the sorting should be firstly by the badge, for example, if an object have a badge "soon" it will be at the top no matter its downloads or its 'datecrea', thank you so much for helping

Comment: Then just reverse the process in the `.sort`

Answer (score 0):

I mean, this isn't a very *clean* method of doing the multi-level sort but...

```
...
.sort(function(a, b) {
   return rankBadge(a) - rankBadge(b);
})

function rankBadge(badge) {
    switch (badge) {
        case "soon": return 3;
        case "new": return 2;
        case "toptem": return 1;
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.sort()` with multiple comparisons. And you can create an object to hold badge ranks to use in sorting.

```js
var items=[{datecrea:"2020-01-31T16:14:46+01:00",datas:{badge:"new",downloads:1}},{datecrea:"2020-02-12T17:14:46+01:00",datas:{badge:"soon",downloads:0}},{datecrea:"2020-01-28T18:14:46+01:00",datas:{badge:"",downloads:3}},{datecrea:"2020-03-31T19:14:46+01:00",datas:{badge:"topten",downloads:5}},{datecrea:"2020-01-31T20:14:46+01:00",datas:{badge:"new",downloads:3}}];

let badgeRanks = {
  soon: 3,
  new: 2,
  topten: 1

}

items.sort(function(item1, item2) {

  let date1 = new Date(item1.datecrea)
  let date2 = new Date(item2.datecrea)

  if (date1.getTime() > date2.getTime()) return -1;
  if (date1.getTime() < date2.getTime()) return 1;

  if (item1.datas.downloads > item2.datas.downloads) return -1;
  if (item1.datas.downloads < item2.datas.downloads) return 1;

  if (badgeRanks[item1.datas.badge] > badgeRanks[item2.datas.badge]) return -1;
  if (badgeRanks[item1.datas.badge] < badgeRanks[item2.datas.badge]) return 1;


});

console.log(items);
```